# How to write an abort-on-error script without adding `|| exit $?` to every line?

Tags: bash, exit

I'm writing a bash script that should exit the error code of the last failed command and not continue execution. This can be achieved by adding a `|| exit $?` everywhere, but is there an easier way, e.g. a `set` option at the start to do this without uglifying every line?

Comment: A side not is that `exit $?` is not needed. By default, your script will exit with the $? of the last command. `exit $?` and `exit` are equivalent in bash.

Comment: @jordanm You mean the `$?` was superfluous? The `exit` itself (without `set -e` as I learned) was necessary. But thanks, good to know for situations where I don't want to abort on _all_ errors.

Comment: Yes, I could have been more clear. The `$?` is superfluous.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`set -e` ?

```
set: set [-abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option-name] [--] [arg ...]
Set or unset values of shell options and positional parameters.

Change the value of shell attributes and positional parameters, or
display the names and values of shell variables.

 Options:
   -a  Mark variables which are modified or created for export.
   -b  Notify of job termination immediately.
   -e  Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status. 
...
```

Comment: Instead of the dummy padding you could quote the documentation.

Comment: there you go :)

Comment: Note that non-zero return codes only cause a `set -e` script to fail when the return codes aren't _tested_. The exact meaning of _tested_ isn't easy to specify, but the basic idea is that `failingcmd || nonfailing` won't make the whole script fail.

Comment: Make sure to read about the [pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Answer (score 3):

You might join all the commands with `&&` and use `|| exit $?` at the very end of the block.
For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
ls ~/folder &&
cp -Rp ~/folder ~/new_folder &&
rm ~/folder/file03.txt &&
echo "This will be skipped..." ||
exit $?
```

if there is no `~/folder/file03.txt` file, the last `echo` command will be skipped. You should receive something like this:

```
$ ./script.ksh
file01.txt  file02.txt
rm: cannot remove /export/home/kkorzeni/folder/file03.txt: No such file or directory
$ echo $?
1
```

Best regards,
Krzysztof

Comment: Hey thanks, and welcome to unix.stackexchange! As jordanm [mentioned](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52063/how-to-write-an-abort-on-error-script-without-adding-exit-to-every-line#comment72826_520639) it turns out `exit` alone will behave the same way as `exit $?` does

Answer (score 3):

You can define a trap function to capture any error that is occurring in the script.

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
trap errtrap

function errtrap {
    es=$?
    echo "`date` The script failed with exit status $es " | $log
}
```

rest of the script follows.

The TRAP will capture any error at any command and will call the `errtrap` function. For better usage you can make the `errtrap` function generic and call that in any script that you are creating.

Comment: Nice, but since you mention `ksh`, does this also work in `bash`?

Comment: It works for bash as well.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but in that case +1 and welcome to unix.SE :)